# Checksumming on Ext4 (crc32c-intel) while formatting (5TB external HDD)

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, hard-disk, ext4, checksum

I bought a new 2.5-inch external hard drive of 5TB in size from Seagate.

On my Linux Mint 21.1 now, I need to format the newly created partition with `gdisk`:

```
Model: Expansion HDD   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 52CB8F84-EFAF-4EC9-B65D-6F8541A65F53
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 9767541133
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      9767541133   4.5 TiB     8300  Seagate_5TB_Ext4
```

visible now with `fdisk` as:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 4.55 TiB, 5000981077504 bytes, 9767541167 sectors
Disk model: Expansion HDD   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 52CB8F84-EFAF-4EC9-B65D-6F8541A65F53

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 9767541133 9767539086  4.5T Linux filesystem
```

and I want to use Ext4 as a file system.

The question is, is there some data checksumming in place by default, or do I need to use some option like explicitly:

```
mkfs.ext4 -O metadata_csum,64bit /dev/path/to/disk
```

as is stated on [Ext4 Metadata Checksums Linux Kernel](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums) page?

Thank you.

Note that I, thus far, used these command-line options for Ext4:

```
mkfs.ext4 -L Seagate_5TB_Ext4 -m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 /dev/sdX
```

Comment: Regarding ext4 in particular && no RAID : What would you expect (in terms of added value) from crc-32 checksumming whatever (data, metadata) ?

Comment: @MC68020 I'd expect slightly better error detection I assume.

Comment: Note that metadata checksumming only covers (some?) filesystem structures, not file contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defaults change over time, and might also depend on your distro.

You can check it yourself with `tune2fs -l`. Format in different ways and compare tune2fs output.

For testing only, you can also create sparse files of identical size. This avoids having to format your existing filesystems for testing.

The size should be similar (or identical) to your intended target device size, as some flags might also depend on size.

```
truncate -s 1T a.img b.img
```

Format them with different flags.

```
mkfs.ext4 a.img
mkfs.ext4 -O metadata_csum,64bit b.img
```

Compare `tune2fs -l` output with `diff -u`:

```
tune2fs -l a.img > a.img.tune2fs
tune2fs -l b.img > b.img.tune2fs
diff -u a.img.tune2fs b.img.tune2fs
```

Result:

```
# diff -U 0 a.img.tune2fs b.img.tune2fs
--- a.img.tune2fs   2023-02-19 14:08:59.338434366 +0100
+++ b.img.tune2fs   2023-02-19 14:09:03.321859687 +0100
@@ -4 +4 @@
-Filesystem UUID:          88952b27-467d-4232-a310-030eaf463d7c
+Filesystem UUID:          b6720761-1fd9-45e6-afd4-2ec7fe63cafb
@@ -29 +29 @@
-Filesystem created:       Sun Feb 19 14:08:35 2023
+Filesystem created:       Sun Feb 19 14:08:39 2023
@@ -31 +31 @@
-Last write time:          Sun Feb 19 14:08:35 2023
+Last write time:          Sun Feb 19 14:08:39 2023
@@ -34 +34 @@
-Last checked:             Sun Feb 19 14:08:35 2023
+Last checked:             Sun Feb 19 14:08:39 2023
@@ -45 +45 @@
-Directory Hash Seed:      efda347d-032b-4d84-81f0-8e86591be3c4
+Directory Hash Seed:      30a3a1b1-682f-4bcc-87f1-909fd577e2fa
@@ -48,2 +48,2 @@
-Checksum:                 0x2fbbf9c2
-Checksum seed:            0x683d2fee
+Checksum:                 0x40316d8f
+Checksum seed:            0x58dc22cf
```

In this case, there was no difference other than UUID, Timestamp, Hash/Checksums. Those are always different, so that's expected. So in my case on my system, specifying `-O metadata_csum,64bit` seems unnecessary.

Adding `-m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0` results in:

```
@@ -15 +15 @@
-Reserved block count:     13421772
+Reserved block count:     0
```

Using `mkfs.ext2` instead of `mkfs.ext4` (just to illustrate that it does show when there are different flags active):

```
@@ -7 +7 @@
-Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index orphan_file filetype extent 64bit flex_bg metadata_csum_seed sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
+Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super large_file
(and many other changes)
```

So this is an example how to use `tune2fs` to check what kind of filesystem mke2fs actually made for you.

For final confirmation, you'll also have to check on the actual device, rather than test files as shown above (mkfs might pick some settings depending on device type).

If it turns out that you picked the wrong flags at mkfs time, some of them can also be changed on the fly (using either tune2fs or resize2fs) without needing to re-format.